# Shephard Distortion for 2 control points distorts entire image - ImageMagick Iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am trying to implement Shephards distortion in iphone. 
Following is my code:

```
const double ctrlPts[8] = {125,200 ,150,150, 255,150, 150, 150};
const size_t q = 8;
MagickDistortImage(magick_wand, ShepardsDistortion , q, ctrlPts, MagickFalse);
```

Following is my result

First One is original Image and second one is distorted image.

[image: Original Image] [image: Distorted Image]

I just want to move one pixel to other location. 
I am not able to figure out where I am making mistake.

I am trying to give Multi-Point and Freeform Distorts from this 
[link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "I just want to move one pixel to other location"?

Comment: I just want to move one pixel from one point to another. Here in the result image you can see a column of pixels are moved and thus the image is distorted. I want to move only one pixel instead of that column.

Comment: Can you post more of your code so it's easier for someone to try this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it simply because you're dragging the image into the center slightly and it doesn't what to put in the gap?

Try setting the corners to be fixed :

```
const double ctrlPts[24] = {
  // Points to move
  125,200 ,150,150, 255,150, 150, 150,

  // Points to fix
  0,0,0,0,   320,0,320,0,   320,460,320,460,    0,460,0,460
};
```

Comment: Cool This Worked... `0,0,0,0,   320,0,320,0,   320,460,320,**460**,    0,460,0,460` One mismatch for 1 parameter..

Comment: Thanks @Dimple Panchal - fixed :)

Comment: Thanks @Matt M - fixed :) (looks like I typed it a bit too quickly!)

Comment: Thanks... Its fixed. Yet the image formed is not what I had expected so again moving to openGL... :(

Comment: After stretching image becomes blurred in that portion... This is not expected to be done..